# What is a Resource Resolver API interface in AEM? What is it's significance

Tags: api, aem, sling, jcr

What exactly are resources and resource resolvers. Can you please elaborate the same and essential terms relating to it?

Wanted to know how resource resolver works and if possible it's usage with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A high level view can be found on https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/resources.html. Sling is essentially the core of AEM.

The easiest way to use a ResourceResolver in a servlet is getting it from [SlingHttpServletRequest.html#getResourceResolver](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling11/org/apache/sling/api/SlingHttpServletRequest.html#getResourceResolver--). The resolver needs to have the appropriate repository rights to access the resource, but every node under `/content` should be accessible.

You could than adapt the node to the appropriate component and get a JSON representation by Jackson mapper.

Comment: Can I access a component it's node and properties using a resource resolver in a service and send them to servlet by converting them in json format? If yes how to do this?

Comment: @Manasi check the extended answer.